# Showing an error during work on PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Showing error while saving one "rainfall.csv" file on another variable on PIG.

`ERROR-- <line 1, column 256>  mismatched input '-' expecting RIGHT_PAREN`

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Please do not post errors as image - post the text. And post the code or script that you've used, anything that shows some effort.

Comment: Similar to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48503572/case-statement-in-pig... *Where are you learning that a hyphen indicates **between two values***?

Answer (score 0):

There are few field names used in PIG script contains "-" (hyphen) e.g. Jan-Feb. Hyphen is not allowed in field name hence error.

Field name should start with a letter and can be followed by any number of letters, digits, or underscores.